# Как поставить Android Media Player на паузу при начале проигрывания из другого приложения

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

Проигрываю трек в сервисе через Android Media Player, подскажите патерн действия для того, что бы ставить проигрывание на паузу когда другое приложение начинает воспроизведеине звука и что бы мой плеер ставил на паузу воспроизведение из других приложений.

Comment: если я правильно понял, вам надо вот это http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/training/managing-audio/audio-focus.html